# A property of $L^{\infty}$.

Tags: functional-analysis, measure-theory

Define in $L^{\infty}$.

$$ \Vert f \Vert_{\infty} = \text{inf}\{M: \vert f(x) \vert \le M \quad \text{for } \mu \text{-almost everywhere  } x\in X\}$$

Prove that $\vert f \vert \leq \Vert f \Vert_{\infty}$  $\mu \text{-almost everywhere}$.

$\textbf{My attempt:}$ Let $M$ such that $\vert f(x) \vert \le M$ in $X-A$ where $\mu(A)=0$. Suppose the opposite. Let's fix an $x \in X-A$, then

$$ \Vert f \Vert_{\infty} < \vert f(x) \vert  $$

By the definition of $\Vert f \Vert_{\infty} $ exists $M_1$ such that

$$ \Vert f \Vert_{\infty} \le M_1 < \vert f(x) \vert $$

$$ \implies M_1 < \vert f(x) \vert \le M_1 $$

A contradiction, so $\vert f \vert \le \Vert f \Vert_{\infty}$ in $\mu \text{-almost everywhere}$.

It´s right? Thanks.

Comment: You use that $M = M_1$ to get the $\implies$ but that's incorrect. You assume that $|f(x)| \leq M$ and then choose $M_1$ such that $M_1 < |f(x)|$. Try instead considering what happens to $x \in X \setminus A$ when $A = \bigcup_{n} A_n$ and $A_n$ is chosen to be a null set such that $|f(x)| \leq \|f\|_\infty + \frac{1}{n}$ for $x \in X \setminus A_n$ (such a null set exists by definition of $\|f\|_\infty$).

Comment: Uhm the existence of $M$ is guaranteed because $f\in L^{\infty}$.

Comment: I agree that there exists an $M$ such that $|f(y)| \leq M$ for all $y \in X \setminus A$ and that if $x \in X \setminus A$ is such that $\|f\|_\infty < |f(x)|$ then there is an $M_1$ such that $\|f\|_\infty \leq M_1 < |f(x)| \leq M$. You do not know that $M_1 = M$ and you do not get for your fixed value of $x$ that $|f(x)| \leq M_1$.

Comment: You are right, thanks. In your first comment I take limit $n\to \infty$?

Comment: Yes, for $x \in X \setminus A$ (with $A$ as in my first comment) you get that $|f(x)| \leq \|f\|_\infty + \frac{1}{n}$ for every $n$ and you send $n \to \infty$ to see that $|f(x)| \leq \|f\|_\infty$.

Answer (score 0):

By definition of infimum, for every $\epsilon >0$:
$$ \lvert f\lvert \leq (\lVert f\lVert_\infty + \epsilon),\quad \mbox{a.e}$$